# Select Columns using single integer in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I loop through Excel columns using a single integer as input such that if

```
myInteger = 1

then

X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B3:B253")
Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("C3:C253")

and if

myInteger = 2

then

X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("D3:D253")
Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("E3:E253")
```

and so on for any value of myInteger (let's say from 1 to 1000 such that manual IF-ELSE doesn't work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using select case

```
Sub test()

myInteger = 1
    Select Case myInteger

    Case 1
        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B3:B253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("C3:C253")

    Case 2


        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("D3:D253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("E3:E253")

    Case Else

        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("D3:D253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("E3:E253")
    End Select
End Sub
```

using If...Else..

```
Sub test()

    myInteger = 1
    If myInteger = 1 Then
        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("B3:B253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("C3:C253")
    ElseIf myInteger = 2 Then


        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("D3:D253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("E3:E253")

    Else

        X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("D3:D253")
        Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("E3:E253")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately myInteger value can go from 1 till say 1000, so doing IF-ELSE or selects don't really work.

I need to match an integer with a column such as 1 ->  B, 2 -> D and so on..

Comment: @acmh if you have the column index and want to find the column name simply use this  `colChr = Split(Cells(, colIndex).Address, "$")(1)`

Comment: @acmh kindly accept the answer if your question is solved. Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to let me know whether I can do this just using something like: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IMVM").Range(Cells(3, myInteger + 1), Cells(253, myInteger + 1)) where myInteger = 1. This line did not work for me, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: `Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IMVM").Range(Cells(3, myInteger + 1), Cells(253, myInteger + 1))` you need assign this range to a range variable using set.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to account for many values and case select/if/else are not appropriate, then try the range `.Offset` method.

Try:

```
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A3:B253").Offset(0,MyInteger)
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A3:B253").Offset(0,MyInteger+1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately myInteger value can go from 1 till say 1000, so doing IF-ELSE or selects don't really work. I need to match an integer with a column such as 1 -> B, 2 -> D and so on..

Comment: Maybe you should've explained that in your question :).  I will revise.

Comment: You're right, apologies for the confusion :) I guess you can call columns and ranges by just numbers..